# Query to compare data between two identical tables along with listing out differences for each column, if any

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two identical tables with same primary key. There are 15 columns or more in each. I need to compare both the tables and list out all the differences. Can we write a generalized plsql block or a query for this?

Output should be something like shown in output table.

Table1:

| Primary Key | Col1 | col2 | col3 | col4(n number of columns) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 439 | 345 | 456 |
| 2 | 239 | 234 | 546 | 5667 |

Table2:

| Primary Key | Col1 | col2 | col3 | col4(n number of columns) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 456 | 345 | 459 |
| 2 | 239 | 234 | 5435 | 4557 |

Output Table:

| Primary Key | Comments | Column Name | Table1 Value | Table2 Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mismatch Found | Col1 | 100 | 200 |
| 1 | Mismatch Found | Col2 | 439 | 456 |
| 1 | Mismatch Found | Col4 | 456 | 459 |
| 2 | Mismatch Found | Col3 | 546 | 5435 |
| 1 | Mismatch Found | Col4 | 5667 | 4557 |

I tried solutions which is giving me a flag where there is match or not. but I'm not able to wrap around my head on how to get the data as well, that too in required format. This was an interview question and I need to crack this for my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.

You can try something like this. Tailor it to fit your needs

```
create table t1(c1 number(2) primary key, c2 varchar2(10), c3 varchar2(10));

 create table t2(c1 number(2) primary key, c2 varchar2(10), c3 varchar2(10));

 insert into t1 values(1,'a','c');
 insert into t2 values(1,'b','c');
 insert into t1 values(2,'a','b');
 insert into t2 values(2,'a','c');
 insert into t1 values(3,'a','b');
 insert into t2 values(3,'a','b');
 insert into t1 values(4,'a','b');
 insert into t2 values(4,'x','y');
 insert into t1 values(5,'a','b');
 insert into t2 values(6,'a','b');

 select case when t1.c1 is null then 'missing in t1'
                when t2.c1 is null then 'missing in t2'
                    end m1,
               decode( t1.c2, t2.c2, '', 'c2' ) c2_flag,
               decode( t1.c3, t2.c3, '', 'c3' ) c3_flag,
               coalesce(t1.c1,t2.c1) pk,
               t1.c2, t2.c2,
               t1.c3, t2.c3
      from t1 full outer join t2 on (t1.c1 = t2.c1)
    where decode( t1.c2, t2.c2, '', 'c2' ) is not null
       or decode( t1.c3, t2.c3, '', 'c3' ) is not null
    order by pk
 

M1  C2_FLAG C3_FLAG PK  C2  C2  C3  C3
 -  c2   -  1   a   b   c   c
 -   -  c3  2   a   a   b   c
 -  c2  c3  4   a   x   b   y
missing in t2   c2  c3  5   a    -  b    - 
missing in t1   c2  c3  6    -  a    -  b
```

Comment: Please refer modified question. I need to get data in that format. That too considering the query/block will be working with huge data and can have 50-60 columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [MODEL clause][1] which allows you to combine data from different rows/columns in a way similar to excel.
Here is the code:

```sql
SELECT ID, COMMENTS, COLUMN_NAME, VALUE_1 "TBL_1_VALUE", VALUE_2 "TBL_2_VALUE"
FROM
    (
        Select  *
        From    ( SELECT 'TBL_1' "TABLE_NAME", t1.* FROM tbl_1 t1 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 'TBL_2' "TABLE_NAME", t2.* FROM tbl_2 t2
                )
        MODEL     PARTITION BY (ID)
                  DIMENSION BY (TABLE_NAME)
                  MEASURES (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, 
                            'Find a mismatch' "COMMENTS", 
                            'Column mismatched' "COLUMN_NAME",
                            CAST(0 AS Number(6)) "VALUE_1", CAST(0 AS Number(6)) "VALUE_2")
                 RULES ( 
                            COMMENTS['CHK1'] = CASE WHEN  COL1['TBL_1'] != COL1['TBL_2'] THEN  'Mismatch Found' END,
                            COMMENTS['CHK2'] = CASE WHEN  COL2['TBL_1'] != COL2['TBL_2'] THEN  'Mismatch Found' END,
                            COMMENTS['CHK3'] = CASE WHEN  COL3['TBL_1'] != COL3['TBL_2'] THEN  'Mismatch Found' END,
                            COMMENTS['CHK4'] = CASE WHEN  COL4['TBL_1'] != COL4['TBL_2'] THEN  'Mismatch Found' END,
                            --
                            COLUMN_NAME['CHK1'] = CASE WHEN  COL1['TBL_1'] != COL1['TBL_2'] THEN 'COL1' END,
                            COLUMN_NAME['CHK2'] = CASE WHEN  COL2['TBL_1'] != COL2['TBL_2'] THEN 'COL2' END,
                            COLUMN_NAME['CHK3'] = CASE WHEN  COL3['TBL_1'] != COL3['TBL_2'] THEN 'COL3' END,
                            COLUMN_NAME['CHK4'] = CASE WHEN  COL4['TBL_1'] != COL4['TBL_2'] THEN 'COL4' END,
                            --
                            VALUE_1['CHK1'] =  CASE WHEN  COL1['TBL_1'] != COL1['TBL_2'] THEN COL1['TBL_1'] END,
                            VALUE_1['CHK2'] =  CASE WHEN  COL2['TBL_1'] != COL2['TBL_2'] THEN COL2['TBL_1'] END,
                            VALUE_1['CHK3'] =  CASE WHEN  COL3['TBL_1'] != COL3['TBL_2'] THEN COL3['TBL_1'] END,
                            VALUE_1['CHK4'] =  CASE WHEN  COL4['TBL_1'] != COL4['TBL_2'] THEN COL4['TBL_1'] END,
                            --
                            VALUE_2['CHK1'] =  CASE WHEN  COL1['TBL_1'] != COL1['TBL_2'] THEN COL1['TBL_2'] END,
                            VALUE_2['CHK2'] =  CASE WHEN  COL2['TBL_1'] != COL2['TBL_2'] THEN COL2['TBL_2'] END,
                            VALUE_2['CHK3'] =  CASE WHEN  COL3['TBL_1'] != COL3['TBL_2'] THEN COL3['TBL_2'] END,
                            VALUE_2['CHK4'] =  CASE WHEN  COL4['TBL_1'] != COL4['TBL_2'] THEN COL4['TBL_2'] END
                        )
    )
WHERE COMMENTS Is Not Null And SubStr(TABLE_NAME, 1, 3) = 'CHK'
ORDER BY ID, COLUMN_NAME
```

With your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    tbl_1 (ID,  COL1,   COL2,   COL3,   COL4) AS
        ( Select 1, 100, 439, 345, 456 From Dual Union All 
            Select 2, 239, 234, 546, 5667 From Dual 
        ),
    tbl_2 (ID,  COL1,   COL2,   COL3,   COL4) AS
        ( Select 1, 200, 456, 345, 459 From Dual Union All 
            Select 2, 239, 234, 5435, 4557 From Dual 
        )
```

... the result should be:

```sql
        ID COMMENTS        COLUMN_NAME       TBL_1_VALUE TBL_2_VALUE
---------- --------------- ----------------- ----------- -----------
         1 Mismatch Found  COL1                      100         200 
         1 Mismatch Found  COL2                      439         456 
         1 Mismatch Found  COL4                      456         459 
         2 Mismatch Found  COL3                      546        5435 
         2 Mismatch Found  COL4                     5667        4557
```

It looks like a lot of code (and it is) but most of it could be copy/paste and in my experience MODEL clause is both - fast and reliable...

**Addition**: Regarding the comment:
Some of initial  values passed to a model clause is too small for later received actual  data. Example: if the table name in 1st union query is 'TAB_1' it will be passed to model as Varchar2(5) which will produce the error in case you use DIMENSION value longer than 5 chars. The same is with the COMMENTS and COLUMN_NAMES defined in MEASURES (or any other value). Initial value for COMMENTS column is 'Find a mismatch' (VarChar2(15)) - actual data longer than 15 chars produce the error. So, it is the size that should be defined not the type. Try to do it like here:

```sql
-- 1st union query
SELECT CAST('TBL_1' as VarChar2(32)) "TABLE_NAME", t1.* FROM tbl_1 t1 UNION ALL
....
....

-- Measures clause
MEASURES (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4, 
          CAST('Find a mismatch' as VarChar2(1000)) "COMMENTS", 
          CAST('Column mismatched' as VarChar2(32)) "COLUMN_NAME",
          CAST(0 AS Number(6)) "VALUE_1", CAST(0 AS Number(6)) "VALUE_2")
```

I don't know your actual data context so you should figure out what is producing the error and do the adjustment.
[1]: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This seem to be working fine for test data but when I’m trying to use the same thing on tables/columns having huge real-time data, I’m getting issue with CAST. ORA-25137 Data value out of range. Tried to use varchar2 with high range but erro persists. Would you be able to help with this?

Comment: @atul Just posted the addition regarding this problem....

Comment: Thanks a ton. This has helped me a lot. I have observed one thing though, if there is null in data from any source, this query is not listing that. Using NVL to compare the values is resulting in all the rows coming as output. First time using MODEL function is causing these many questions for different test case scenarios. Let me know if you can tell me how NULLs can be handled as well.

Comment: @atul It depends on where null comes from and what you want to do with it, but you can do  CAST(Null as VarChar2(32))  or CAST(Null as Number(6)) or ..... Model needs to know type and size of data being processed. Null values are not excepted.